# Can I hitchhike on a yacht to cross the Mediterranean from Spain to Turkey?

Tags: turkey, spain, sea-travel, hitchhiking, mediterranean

I've heard occasionally of people managing to get passage on yachts and other boats and I would like to try this. How can I find a boat to ride on and what would be the likely conditions of carriage?

Comment: May depend a lot on your skill level - do you already know how to sail / crew, and how much experience of doing it do you have?

Comment: I can windsurf well but no crew experience. I'm able bodied and willing however.

Comment: There are tips on nautical hitchhiking on both [WikiVoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Hitchhiking_boats) and [HitchWiki](http://hitchwiki.org/en/Hitchhiking_a_boat).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your best bet is to sign up to a crew-finding website like [findacrew.net](http://www.findacrew.net).  A friend who cycled from London to New Zealand did this for the ocean parts - hung out in port and used the site.

What was observed is that there are different levels of opportunities.  Some berths require that you have licenses or sailing experience, or a particular skill (eg cooking), while others will take anyone.

The alternative, if you have the time (like she did) is to hang out by the docks and ask people - even if they aren't taking anyone, they may have heard of someone who is.  Often it's just spur of the moment opportunity.

Comment: Sometimes it's also worth popping down to the marina(s) if you're already nearby, or when you get there. This will depend on how easy it is to find the ones the yachties use, and what their policies regarding letting in non members are. Years ago we wandered into a marina in Isla Mujeres, Mexico and the guy in our group with sailing experience got many offers. But I don't know if it's still so easy or how it will go in other places.